# Why does My teleporter part Not teleport to another part

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently working on a game teleporter in Roblox (If you are unfamiliar with this, you touch a part and It takes you to a waiting area to soon be teleported to the game) Right now I am having trouble with the part that teleports you to that waiting area. (the name of the part teleporting you is called Teleporter. The name of the part you are being teleported to is called Lob)
[image: Code][image: Error]

The code I had put In was `

```
local Lob = game.Workspace.Lob

function Teleport()
    game.Workspace.Teleporter.Touched:Connect(game.Players.LocalPlayer:MoveTo(Lob))
end

game.Workspace.Teleporter.Touched:Connect(Teleport)
```

`What i got was`ServerScriptService.Script:4: attempt to index nil with 'MoveTo'`

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting the touched event inside of the function and outside of it.

Could you possibly do something like

```
function Teleport()
    game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = Lob.CFrame)
end

workspace.Teleporter.Touched:Connect(Teleport)
```